# How can we easily revert the changes made by experiements with unfamiliar commands?

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, container, sandbox

Sometimes I would like to experiment with some commands which I am unfamiliar with (e.g. `xmodmap`), and also have the ability to revert the changes very easily without knowing much about the commands yet.  Do I need some kind of light-weight virtualization or container (e.g. Docker) or sandbox? I am running Ubuntu 16.04 with LXDE. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you set up a VM in either Virtual Box or VMware Workstation (VMware Player does not support snapshots), snapshot the VM, do your experiments, and then revert to the snapshot whenever you need a "known to be good" operating system environment.

Comment: VMware Player doesn't support snapshots, but I assume there would be nothing wrong with using `cp -p` on the _shutdown_ guest image files. Other than a doubling of disk space usage, that is.

Comment: @roaima  Thanks. Do you mean that " using `cp -p` on the shutdown guest image files" does not double the disk space usage? I maybe misunderstood, but does `cp -p` not copy the image file?

Comment: @Tim since Player won't let you snapshot a guest, you would have to copy the entire guest image to emulate a snapshot. If the image is 20GB then the copy would also be 20GB. Contrast with a true snapshot where the extra disk space required is only that required to store changes made since the snapshot has been taken.

Comment: @roaima. The "image" size largely depends on the disk provisioning method, the number of snapshots, and changes made since snapshotting.  If a 20Gb disk is thin-provisioned, the underlying physical file or files will typically be  significantly smaller on a new VM.

Comment: Yes thank you. I'm aware of that. Possibly Tim isn't though.

Answer (score 2):

You may be interrested in **[Qubes OS](https://www.qubes-os.org)**, which enables you to run many Linux (or any other OS) containers using one or more OS templates.

For example we can use **Debian template**, install required software packages on it and than run the containers (personal, work and **experiments**).

In this scenario, anything you will do in experiments container, does not affect the template itself, or any other container at all.

In Qubes OS VM Manager you can make **snapshots** too, just like in VirtualBox.

Comment: Thanks. What level of virtualation does Qubes OS belong to? For comparison, Docker belongs to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operating-system-level_virtualization

Comment: **HVM/KVM** on Xen hypervisor. You can find Qubes OS architecture overview [here](https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/architecture/).